# pulling Dict values in a loop

Tags: python, networkx

I'm having trouble isolating the values of a graphs edge weight in networkx
Im using kruskals algorithm to find a the MST of a given graph. U and V are point in Euclidean space and data is a dictionary for the weight of each edge. I'm using the values function for dictionaries to store the value in the set however I am returned this error

```
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py", line 1143, in to_numpy_array
  A[index[u], index[v]] = d.get(weight, 1)
  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

the particular piece of code I am having trouble with is this.

```
for u,v, data in sorted(self.original_graph.edges(data=True), key=lambda x: x[2]['weight']):
        setu = UF.find(u)
        setv= UF.find(v)

        if setu != setv:
            A.append((u,v,data.values()))
            UF.union(setu,setv)
```

I am fully aware that networkx has their own minimum spanning tree functions built in, however I am trying to learn these algorithms on my own instead before blindly implementing built in functions

Answer (score 0):

Upon reading into the documents for python, I realized that data.values() returns a list of all values in the dict, what I needed to do was reference the key such as data['weight'] in order to get the value it holds.